# Latex define font for entire document

Tags: fonts, times

Here is my tex sample.  I got one problem that, my entire document font changed back to default. In the beginning I have

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\renewcommand\bibname{References}


\usepackage{lmodern}


\author{XXX}
\title{USER Instruction}
\begin{document}






\tableofcontents

\newpage
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures

\newpage
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\listoftables















\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}


\subsection{Data}
it can be divided into two operations: 


\section{The pt}

\chapter{ASA }

llllllllllllllll




\chapter{Cooo}

k

\chapter{CoooK}

lkkkkkkkkk
\section{CoooWork}

In th

\bibliography{Bibliography}












\end{document}
```

Which gives me similar with Times font. But it just changed someday, and I tried many ways can not get the Times font. The font does not change whatever I do....can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: LaTeX changes font only when it's ordered to. A minimal example showing the issue is needed: it's likely that when you'll be preparing it, you'll find the cause.

Comment: [hints for preparing a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/)

Comment: Minimal? Anyways, why do you load `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. you are totally right....this is the problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `\usepackage{mathptmx}` followed later by `\usepackage{lmodern}`.  This means that the `mathptmx` font choices and settings are applied first and then they are overridden by those from `lmodern` (which is close to the default LaTeX font).  So all you need to do is remove the `\usepackage{lmodern}`.